# Angular mat-button:hover background color works, if I use a color other than white

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, hover

Trying to set a custom background color for the `:hover` state on my Angular `mat-button`

Here's the html:
`<button mat-button class="my-mat-button">Click</button>`

Then my css in my `styles.sass`

```
.my-mat-button:hover
  background-color: red !important
```

This works to change the hover state to red.

But when I change the css to

```
.my-mat-button:hover
  background-color: white !important
```

This results in the hover state being a gray color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The buttons background-color is working as expected and also your code is all correct.

I rebuild your issue in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-btn-hover-white-background). If you look at the "warn"-buttons you can see the background color is working.

I think the problem is that the opacity of the button is changing on hover.
I searched in the angular material code and found this:

```
// Only basic and stroked buttons (not raised, FABs or icon buttons) have a hover 
style.
// Use the same visual treatment for hover as for focus.
.mat-button:hover,
.mat-stroked-button:hover {
  .mat-button-focus-overlay {
    opacity: 0.04;
  }
}
```

So your button is starting white but than some kind of fading out. You can see this in the example, too. You can lookup the original stylsheet [here](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/button/button.scss).

Comment: Thank you for figuring that out. Really amazing of you to take the time.

Comment: No problem! I've got to work with "angular material", too. So somehow it helps not only you but myself, too.